# strip a div and all child elements from a string with JavaScript replace RegEx

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex, replace

I have a block of HTML stored in a variable called `address_form`, within that block of HTML I want to remove, or replace, a portion of it. The part I want to replace is a div with an ID of `address_container`.

There's clearly something wrong with my RegEx here that i'm using with the replace function as it is not working:

`var tempStr = address_form.replace('/\<div id=\"#address_container\"\>.*<\/div\>/', '');`

I simply want to replace a string, within a string.

Comment: please post the block of HTML

Comment: You should at least remove the single quotes wrapping the regex, because it will be a string and not a regex :-)

Comment: If you want to modify HTML code with JavaScript, why not insert it into an element outside of the document and do the modifications via DOM methods?

Comment: @Sirko was thinking the same thing..and if u need the content as a string you could just get  the content by saying outerHTML

Comment: You've tagged the question with the jQuery tag.  If you are going to use jQuery, don't prefix the id with # - it'll break any future jQuery selectors for that element.

Comment: Correctly matching a `DIV` element, (which itself may contain other `DIV` elements), using a single JavaScript regex is _impossible_. This is because the js regex engine does not support matching nested structures.

Comment: @ridgerunner Thanks for your comment, it appears you are absolutely correct here. I was unable to use the code below submitted as answers to resolve the problem as I could not match a `div` with a JavaScript RegEx. Would you like you submit this as an answer as I will gladly accept.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From @RidgeRunner

> Correctly matching a DIV element, (which itself may contain other DIV
>   elements), using a single JavaScript regex is impossible. This is
>   because the js regex engine does not support matching nested
>   structures.

Comment: @Simon, it's not a solution - but it's an *answer* to the question I posed.

Comment: You didn't really pose a question, just stated a problem. The solution to your problem would be the one Brian Ball posted.

Comment: Just to clear that, I voted you down because if someone, being in the same position as you, is looking for a solution here, he would just find that there seems to be none while there actually is one.

Comment: @Simon Disagree. I tried Brian Ball's solution and it didn't quite work, plus I *did* ask RidgeRunner to add the answer.

Comment: So you just go with "not possible" instead of trying to implement Brian Ball's code correctly? It probably would help if you could post what exact string your ´address_form´ is, to figure out why Brian's code didn't work at first try...

Answer (score 2):

Since you've tagged your question with jQuery, then I would suggest you use jQuery to do this task. Something like:

```
var tempStr = jQuery(address_from).remove('#address_container').html();
```

Comment: +1 - that's how I'd do it, but I know more about the Twilight series than I do regular expressions.  I've never seen any of the Twilight series.

Comment: +1, that's the real solution. I would remove the .html() at the end and work with the jQuery object, though.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do that, just get the contents of the div and replace the parent of that div with the contents.

So

```
var tempStr = $('#address_container').html(); // or text()
$('#parent_of_address_container').html(tempStr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is wrong.  Use this instead:

```
address_form.replace(/<div id=["-]#address_container["-]>.*<\/div>/,'');
```